# How can I create Hive tables from AWS S3 bucket from my local machine?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, create-table, hiveddl

I am trying to create hive table from S3 location but I am getting error. This is my query

```
hive> create external table if not exists external_sales(invoice_id string,
branch string,
customer_type string,
gender string,
product_category string,
price int,
quantity int,
tax float,
total float,
purchase_date string,
ptime string,
payment_mode string,
cogs float,
gross_margin_p float,
gross_income float,
rating float)
location's3n://rawdata831547/csv_data/supermarket_sales.csv'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Error -

> No FileSystem for scheme "s3n"

Also tried `S3a://`, `s3n://`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this bug: [HIVE-13996](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13996)

Try to add hadoop libraries path to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH (in the shell before running hive):

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
```

You can check the hadoop classpath with this:

```
bin/hadoop classpath
```